# Tabs in wordpress admin area?

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently using Advanced Custom fields ALOT, and there is ALOT of them in the homepage.

Basically, I am trying to set a number of tabs across the top of the admin page, when a user edits certain pages.

For instance, when the user edits 'home', there will be tabs at the top where I can place different content for the user, instead of it all being listed out?

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each field group is a metabox.
U can use a third party plugin to create tabs. (resource: http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/group-different-custom-field-groups-into-tabs/)

An example for a third party plugin is http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-metabox-tabs/

I hope this answers your question.